# How to change logo src, when clicked on hamburger menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When clicked on hamburger menu, I want to change the brand logo color (src) with another SVG image, because the background doesn't fit.

OnClick hamburger change Brand logo with another image

How could I do that?

I know how to change with an event.listener the element who is being clicked, not other element which I need

```
const navSlide = () => {
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.header__links');
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.header__links a');   

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // toggle nav
    nav.classList.toggle('header__nav-active');

    // animate links 
    navLinks.forEach((a, index) => {
        if (a.style.animation) {
            a.style.animation = '';
        } else {
            a.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 6 + 0.3}s`;
            a.style.color = `#ffffff`;
        }
    });
});
}

 navSlide();
```

I have this following JS code. I need to change logo on click hamburger, else, stay the same .

Comment: You can something like this with pure CSS https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=changing-image-on-hover-with-css

Comment: Thanks for you'r help, but this is not the case, as I said, i need to change another elements logo (src) with another image, when I click on the hamburger menu icon.

Comment: can u post HTML code?

Comment: Consider to follow minimal-reproducible-example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you write a question otherwise we are not able to help you

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('.logoClass').src = "Images/New-Image-Source.png";` when the click `eventHandler` is fired

Answer (score 1):

something like this can help you:

```
hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.yourBrandLogoImg').src = "some/path/to/logo.svg";
}
```

and if you want toggle this src you can do something like this:

```
hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {

    if (nav.classList.contains('header__nav-active')){
        document.querySelector('.yourAnotherImg').src = "some/path/to/anotherImg.svg";
    }else{
        document.querySelector('.yourBrandLogoImg').src = "some/path/to/yourLogo.svg";
}
```

Comment: I just commented the exact same thing, wasn't sure if it would work though so didn't post an answer. +1 to you

Comment: this will work, but i think the author wants to toggle this src on click humburger, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the `logo` is outside the `hamburger` container.
Here is the code of changing the image:

https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/QWWqxXL?editors=1010

Thanks